# Reduce vibration by bench grinder

Tags: vibration, grinder

I live on the 2nd story. I would like to reduce the vibration caused by the bench grinder. I bought the grinder at least 30 years ago. Everything is original equipment. I have some carpet padding under it, but a lot of vibration is still transmitted to my floor.

Can you suggest some other ideas that will preferably cost the least.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Typically the only thing that will cause the vibration on grinder wheels like yours, are the wheels themselves being out of balance. My suggestion would be to get two new wheels (grinding stones).

Comment: I rarely use the wire brush, so I won't replace it. The diameter is about 6 inches. What are my options? I don't not need brand recommendations but just the names of useful items. I pretty much only sharpen things or just to shorten bolts.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are definitely right.

Comment: I thought that may have been a wire brush there, typically I have seen and used grinders with two different grits of wheels, one very coarse and a finer one. To check the vibration, remove both wheels and turn it on. It will most likely be so quiet you can barely hear it from a short distance.

Answer (score 0):

Can see why on that counter, try a rubber mat and add foam then your carpet pad. Some felt on the grinder or rubber legs will help to,1/2 inch or 3/4 rubber legs on grinder will absorb a lot of vibration.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a thick rubber mat and ensuring the unit is functioning properly are good things to plan to do, but one thing not mentioned, and it matters, is density. That countertop/work area appears to be makeshift. If you have a rigid structure (the heavier the better), to place your mat on, you will drastically reduce the vibrations to the floor.

You could build something if need be; but I suspect you will be better off with a solid table+mat. You could then also place insulators or rubber mats under the legs of the table.

Comment: It sits on a dresser as I am limited in space. I could put something under the legs of the dresser.

Comment: This is only half of the spring mass system. The other is mass for example a 50lb iron mass under the grinder would greatly reduce the amount of transferred vibration.

Comment: Yep, when I said density, I meant mass, but alas, they go hand in hand in practicality.

Comment: @Dan D. 50 lbs of mass is a little impractical. Need something a little easier.

Comment: Dan was making a point & 50 lbs is quite practical. Given the variables at play I cannot say how well a 50 lb anything will work, **BUT** Go spend $4.67 at Big Orange and buy a bag of play sand. It will do everything you need all in one package. Proof of concept and cheap too. All three answers here give you the things to consider to solve your predicament, now go see how you choose to implement them. I'm confident $5 and the sand will put your mind at ease of what Don Quixote can accomplish

Comment: Oh, and for clarity, I'm suggesting the bag of sand on the floor as a test. You might find putting it on the tablepictured might get noisy. Simle cheap test tho!